# Generate new array of object from comparing object keys in dynamic array of object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

```
const payload = [
  {
    ControlType: 'Label',
    Property: 'FirstName'
  },
  {
    ControlType: 'DateTime',
    Property: 'CreatedOn'
  },
  {
    ControlType: 'Label',
    Property: 'Price'
  },
  {
    ControlType: 'Label',
    Property: 'SubTotal'
  },
  {
    ControlType: 'Label',
    Property: 'Total'
  }
];

const object1 = {
  ContactId: null,
  ContactName: null,
  CreatedOn: '05-06-2020 12:37 PM',
  CustId: '4069241-BR02',
  CustName: 'ABC',
  FirstName: 'Test',
  LastName: 'Test',
  SurName : 'Test',
  Total:500,
  Price: 200,
  SubTotal:400,
  Tax:100,
  Qty : 2
};
```

// I need below results

```
const newResult = [
  {
    FirstName: 'Test',
    ControlType: 'Label'
  },
  {
    CreatedOn: '05-06-2020 12:37 PM',
    ControlType: 'DateTime'
  },
  {
    Price: 200,
    ControlType: 'Label'
  },
  {
    SubTotal: 400,
    ControlType: 'Label'
  },
  {
    Total: 500,
    ControlType: 'Label'
  }
];
```

Comment: please add the code, you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the items of your array, add for each item the value of the key that is in Property, found in object1, and delete the Property key:

```
payload.map(function(item){
    item[item.Property] = object1[item.Property];
    delete item["Property"];
    return item;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` it:

```js
var payload = [ { ControlType: 'Label', Property: 'FirstName' }, { ControlType: 'DateTime', Property: 'CreatedOn' }, { ControlType: 'Label', Property: 'Price' }, { ControlType: 'Label', Property: 'SubTotal' }, { ControlType: 'Label', Property: 'Total' }];

var object1 = { ContactId: null, ContactName: null, CreatedOn: '05-06-2020 12:37 PM', CustId: '4069241-BR02', CustName: 'ABC', FirstName: 'Test', LastName: 'Test', SurName : 'Test', Total:500, Price: 200, SubTotal:400, Tax:100, Qty : 2};

var result = payload.map(({Property, ...rest})=>({[Property]:object1[Property], ...rest}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and destructuring

```js
const convert = (arr, obj) =>
  arr.map(({ ControlType, Property }) => ({
    [Property]: obj[Property],
    ControlType,
  }));

const payload = [
  {
    ControlType: "Label",
    Property: "FirstName",
  },
  {
    ControlType: "DateTime",
    Property: "CreatedOn",
  },
  {
    ControlType: "Label",
    Property: "Price",
  },
  {
    ControlType: "Label",
    Property: "SubTotal",
  },
  {
    ControlType: "Label",
    Property: "Total",
  },
];

const object1 = {
  ContactId: null,
  ContactName: null,
  CreatedOn: "05-06-2020 12:37 PM",
  CustId: "4069241-BR02",
  CustName: "ABC",
  FirstName: "Test",
  LastName: "Test",
  SurName: "Test",
  Total: 500,
  Price: 200,
  SubTotal: 400,
  Tax: 100,
  Qty: 2,
};

console.log(convert(payload, object1));
```